# Different data display to each user

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a mysql table from which I need to show single row at a time to each user with condition that if a particular row is shown to a user, then that row not show to other user.

I can use status field to lock that row but what if two or more select query hits on same time.

Can someone please help me in building this logic?

Comment: Queries are not hit at the same time. There's a millisecond or less perid between'em

Comment: if you are using a status field, you would need to consider the order in which you do things. You would need to lock it, then open it rather than the other way around.